# Bootstrap 4 nav bar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

Bom dia
Este é o código que uso na minha barra de menu, mas quando faz o collapse o botão fica ao tamanho todo da barra fazendo subir o icon do logo, eu queria que o botão do collapse fica-se como devia ficar (quadrado).
O código css é do Bootstrap4

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/#.png" alt="#" width="25" height="25"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#.php">#</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#.php">#</a></li>
            <!--li><a class="nav-link" href="#.php?id=">#</a></li-->
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#.php">#</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#.php">#</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#.php">#</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="password.php">Password</a>
            </li>
            <li clas="nav-item">
                <?php 
                    date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Lisbon");
                    echo '<a class="nav-link">'.date("d-m-Y").'</a>';
                ?>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo $logoutAction ?>">Logout</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Adelino usando o Bootstrap-4 e sem adicionar nenhum outro CSS aqui funcionou normalmente no Chrome e no FireFox.

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-grid.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-reboot.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">

Comment: Um desses CSS está conflitando como o CSS do CDN original do Bootstrap4. E outra coisa, os arquivos "bootstrap-grid.min.css" e "bootstrap-grid.css" são os mesmos, vc não precisa indexar os dois. A diferença é que o .MIN.CSS é a versão minificada do CSS, mas os dois são iguais, chame apenas um deles na sua página.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veja ai o seu código rodando no **BS4**, não apresentou BUG, só comentei os `<script>` para não dar *erro* no *snippet* do StackOverflow

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-top">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="http://placeskull.com/16/16" alt="#" width="25" height="25"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li><a class="nav-link" href="#.php">#</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link" href="#.php">#</a></li>
                <!--li><a class="nav-link" href="#.php?id=">#</a></li-->
                <li><a class="nav-link" href="#.php">#</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link" href="#.php">#</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link" href="#.php">#</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="password.php">Password</a>
                </li>
                <li clas="nav-item">
                    <?php 
                        date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Lisbon");
                        echo '<a class="nav-link">'.date("d-m-Y").'</a>';
                    ?>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo $logoutAction ?>">Logout</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    
    <!-- <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script> -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Acabei de retirar o meu codigo e substituir pelos links e acontece o mesmo

Comment: i.stack.imgur.com/Xok21.png

Comment: @AdelinoVasconcelos aqui está a documentação oficial do BS4 sobre a NavBar https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/ e aqui vc pode ver alguns exemplos rodando. O problema é que eu não estou conseguindo simular o seu Erro ai não consigo ajudar. Mas nesse link vc pode fazer alguns testes. https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_navbar.asp clique no "Try it Yourself" e vai brincando com o código e aperta "RUN" no topo.

Comment: já consegui obrigado a mesma